# VSTS: query to get work items completed within 75% of estimated effort

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have fields for "Estimated Effort" (Decimal) and "Actual Effort" (Decimal).

I want to get all work items that have been completed within 75% of the estimated effort. Is there a way to write a query for it or if not is there any possible alternate(a plugin..)?

Also, can we attach images to VSTS dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No we cannot achieve that by work item query, calculations is not supported within the work item fields.

As far as I know no such an extension or a plugin can achieve that. There's an extension called [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-server-plugin), it can sum up totals on a single work item (`i.e. Dev Estimate + Test Estimate = Total Estimate`), but it's not apply to calculate the percentage.

> can we attach images to VSTS dashboard?

No, we cannot attach images to dashboard, however you can checkin the images into VSTS repository or save the images to any other sites which VSTS can access them, then add widgets (i.e. `Markdown`) in dashboard and add the image hyperlinks in Markdown. Thus you can navigate to the images by clicking the hyperlinks.

Comment: You can show the image in the MD widget, you don't need to put a link to the image. for example: `![Test Image](http://link/to/image.png)`